# How can I convert a disk from ext4 to ext2?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, ext2

I have Ubuntu with a root volume using ext4.

I need to downgrade it so that it is using ext2.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to say you would need to re-format the volume.